# Reactjs turn off shorthand inline style helper

Tags: css, reactjs

Currently, reactjs does an awesome job of assuming that everything should be pixel. But in some cases, I actually don't need it to do the helper stuff. I know this is great for height and percentage:

`{height: 100}` or `{height: 100%}` but in other cases I need it for actual numbers, like this property:

`WebkitAnimationIterationCount: 2` results to `-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2px`

How can I escape the pixel!

Comment: You could maybe use the `animation` shorthand which would require a string instead of the specific count property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Comment: Or, for a simple hack, try using the value `'2;'`, as it bypasses React's number check when it builds the `style` string.

Answer (score 2):

After digging into react's source code, I would say that this is not yet possible (react 0.13.1):

- There is a hardcoded list of unitless properties here: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v0.13.1/src/browser/ui/dom/CSSProperty.js#L17 and `animationIterationCount` is not among them
- Anything not in that list will have 'px' appended to it: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v0.13.1/src/browser/ui/dom/dangerousStyleValue.js#L28

(Maybe an opportunity to contribute to React?)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I found a hack:

`WebkitAnimationIterationCount: 'calc(2)'` ended up working, although a suggestion of `'2;'` should work too!